# How to upload videos faster to a server?

Tags: web-applications

I have captured a 900 MB video and want to transfer it to a server from my PC. I try to upload this with Filezilla, but it takes so long, like few hours, and I have fast Internet connection as well. So are there any free programs that can be installed on the PC and used for fast transfer of videos? Any other suggestions are greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance, Adia:)

Comment: Upload it to where?  Remember, the server's bandwidth matters too.

Comment: To any server, e.g. a server where my web page is.

Answer (score 2):

You could for example use [Handbreak](http://handbrake.fr/) to encode the video in a smaller format. I'd suggest to use H.264 (x264) as it can produce good quality at low bitrates (to the quality/size ratio is good) and is widely supported. If you're completely unexperienced with this you'll probably need to try around a bit with the options, but Handbreak makes it fairly easy. However, remember the smaller the file the worse the quality in the end. Also it's better if you have good quality in the source material as the compression can usually work more efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to say no. Your limited by the server's net connection and your own

Also, a fast internet connection can have different meaning to different people. I have 50mb broadband but someone else might consider 8mb as fast. Plus remember, you uprate is usually around 10x slower than your down rate on your connection. Sometimes more, sometimes less.

The alternative to waiting is to transcode your video to a smaller size before uploading

Comment: Yes, I am aware of those, thanks. I was wondering if there were such programs. Because there are sites where one can upload photos to be developed and they have programs that once installed can be used for transferring the photos faster. I thought that there might be such things for video too:) Thanks again for your reply:)